May I write an answer to a question I do not find anymore?
As I wrote yesterday, I am unable to find anymore a question I found interesting (I remember all the details of it).
May I post an answer ?
Edit
In the parent question, good news since @Matthew Towers found that the question is Approximate a known function by a sum of real power function.

I say, absolutely.  I'd reference the unfindable question as the inspiration for the work, and of course, edit should the source be discovered.  But it sounds like good mathematics and worth having.

Your link went to your answer to the question, but I assumed it was meant to be to the question itself, so I edited accordingly.  I hope that that was all right.

In general, nobody can prevent you or grant permission here, hence you can, of course, post answers to existing questions.
"May I post an answer?": You will have to make your relevant question post  in order to post your answer.
In effect, it will look like answering your own question.
Echoing what lulu said, you might want to mention the earlier question & later you might want to include references to it.
